# Mac Mail 11.4 mark as read delay - High Sierra

Tags: mail.app, email, high-sierra

Is there a similar solution for Mail App on High Sierra as it was on older versions (I think, Yosemite Mail App). There was a command line to adjust the mark as read delay. See this (for older Mail Apps):

```
defaults write com.apple.mail MarkAsReadDelay 5
```

I want to achieve that mails won't be marked as read, directly.